# copy file in command prompt with Arabic file name

Tags: cmd, copy, arabic

How can I copy a file with Arabic characters in the name via the command prompt?

I tried this:

```
copy C:\توزيع العمل.doc D:\توزيع العمل.doc
```

It didn't work. What I can do to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap file path to quotes. Like this "C:\توزيع العمل.doc".
So final command will look like.

`copy "C:\توزيع العمل.doc" "D:\توزيع العمل.doc"`